# $x^3=2y^3+4z^3$ in the set of integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $x, y, z$ are integers solve:
$$x^3=2y^3+4z^3$$

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?

Comment: I see one really obvious solution, can you find it?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the solution.

First notice that $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ is a solution. 
If only one of $x,y,z$ is $0$ then we get a contradiction.
If two of $x,y,z$ are equal to $0$ then we get the above solution.

Let's assume that none of $x,y,z$ is equal to $0$. In that case:
$$x=2^ka$$
$$y=2^mb$$
$$z=2^nc$$
where $$a,b,c,k,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$k,m,n\ge0$$
and $a,b,c$ are odd numbers

From the equation $x^3$ is even, so $x$ is even. The equation becomes:
$$(2\cdot 2^{k-1}a)^3=2y^3+4z^3$$
$$4(2^{k-1}a)^3=y^3+2z^3$$
In the same way y and z are even and we get $(2^{k-1}a)^3=2(2^{m-1}b)^3+4(2^{n-1}c)^3$. Repeating the same until one of $k,m,n$ gets eliminated we conclude that one of $a,b,c$ is an even number, hence a contradiction.

Comment: The obvious question: What about x^3=2y^3+5z^3? For what constants does this work?

Comment: It is obvous that you are looking for a formula that doesn't care of the coefficients, but as you have ssen, you have to.